# My battery is completely dead

Tags: windows-7, battery

So I haven't charged my laptop in 6 years and the battery is completely dead. If I charge it will turn on but if I disconnect it will turn off. Do I have to replace my battery?

Comment: Yes, you do ...

Comment: For six years, I think any battery storage device would be more or less problematic. If you can only use DC power, then I don't think the battery is charging. Replacing the battery is an option. I remember there was also a command under Windows to view the power issue. “powercfg/batteryreport”. This will give a detailed HTML report on battery issues, charge ratings, history of battery use and history of battery charge periods.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using [BatteryInfoView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/battery_information_view.html) by NirSoft to view detailed info about your battery.

> **Description**
>
> BatteryInfoView is a small utility for laptops and netbook
>   computers that displays the current status and information about your
>   battery. The displayed battery information includes the battery name,
>   manufacture name, serial number, manufacture date, power state
>   (charging/discharging), current battery capacity, full charged
>   capacity, voltage, charge/discharge rate, and more...

For your situation, check the `Current Capacity (in %)` line.

If your battery no longer has sufficient capacity to hold a charge, you will indeed need to replace it.

[image]

Comment: Might not work on a 6-year old battery, especially if it's all but dead.

Comment: @harrymc As long as the battery is recognized, I don't see why it shouldn't work. I have a 20 year old Win98 laptop that recognizes the battery as being plugged in, even though it holds zero charge.

Comment: NIce utility, NirSoft is great.